# SeekBar is jerky during playback

Tags: java, android, audio, view, seekbar

Basically i'm using seek bar to show to user how audio playback is going, my visual update is presented in `Thread` and looks like this :

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(mUpdating) {
        if(mSeekBar != null) {
            mSeekBar.setProgress(mAudioPlaybackManager.getCurrentPosition());
        }
        //Other stuff is updating
    }
}
```

So, for exqample if user plays audio that's 2500 ms in length, this `SeekBar` max value will be 2500 and it will be updating every ms

*This same code working much slower in `runOnUiThread`, so i'm guessing when progress is changed something like `postInvalidate` is called*

So basically every ms, the seekbar value should be changed. I guess that's the problem here. On my device `Samsung J7` it's working smoothly but on `Samsung Galaxy S5` it's just stopping and jumping all the time, like if i put this code in `runOnUIThread`, it would be really slow.

What could i do to make it smoother? Is there another `View` that i can use for this pirpose?

The things that current `SeekBar` is doing:

- Showing progress of audio basically in `while(updating)`
- When user changes the position of `SeekBar` audio is starting from that point.

Answer (score 0):

The thread is a worker thread and not UI's thread, you're manipulating UI component within the thread thus blocking the UI's thread.

If you want to update the seekbar, update it in UI's thread. It can be done with UI's thread handler.

For example

```
private Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //get current position
            timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            //set seekbar progress
            seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);

      //repeat yourself again in 100 miliseconds
        durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
```

Executed in

```
public void play(View view) {

      mediaPlayer.start();

        while(mUpdating) {
           if(mSeekBar != null) {
             // post the Runnable (updateSeekBarTime)
             durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100); 
          }
        }
    }
```

Also updating component can't simply be done every millisecond, from user perspective, giving a bit pause won't be noticed.

Comment: So, using our approach: with delay it's very laggy and slow, if i set no delay or 1 ms, it's going smooth, but i don't think that there is difference with Thread, we should see if it will work on that device, i'm not sure about this

Comment: Could you provide more of your codes so I can mimic it, I'm suspecting there's something wrong over this `mUpdating` that could probably delay the operation on the seekbar. Rapid updating on UI has always been a problem, though, on some cases will work flawlessly due to fast/good hardwares support on the device itself.